# ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified in python

Tags: python, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect Oracle SQL DB using cx_Oracle python library. my tns looks something like this .

```
DEVNDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.213.151)(PORT = 1515))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = devnc12c)
    )
   )
```

I tried with this code .

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="NCSWEB", password="pwd", dsn="devnc12c")
cur = con.cursor()
```

but getting below error

```
PS C:\Users\ncdex1124> python .\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="NCSWEB", password="pwd", dsn="devnc12c")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have checked Network Alias name in properties in Oracle SQL Developer its "DEVNDB" and connection is also success with above username and password. unfortunately I can't attach image of DB properties as reputation is below 10 at the moment.

Comment: Shouldn't the dsn be `DEVNDB`?

Comment: Fix the DSN as suggested in the comment.  For reference, a goto source for connection errors is: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/